# file_get_contents returning false instead of is_readable true

Tags: php, file, upload, file-get-contents

I'm just having some trouble working with $_FILES and file_get_contents.

```
$nomFichier = $_FILES['pieceJointe']['name'];
echo is_readable($_FILES['pieceJointe']['tmp_name']);
echo $_FILES['pieceJointe']['error'];
if(file_get_contents($_FILES['pieceJointe']['tmp_name']) == false)
{
        echo "impossible de lire le fichier.<br/>";
}
else
{ 
         // store the file into a BLOB field in my database
}
```

is_readable display "1", $_FILES['pieceJointe']['error'] says 0.
But file_get_contents return false.

I notice that happen only with files which the name contains accents.
Everything is working fine with only letters/numbers file names.

Do I missed something ?

ps: I'm french student, not professional, sorry for my english :o

Thx!

Comment: Make sure your error reporting is turned up.  If `file_get_contents()` is returning false, it should also be emitting an error which will give you more information.

Comment: My error reporting is turned up, error_reporting(-1);

Answer (score 0):

Use `var_dump` to see the actual value of `is_readable()`. The "1" that you see is actually the output of `$_FILES['pieceJointe']['error']` which means the file you are trying to upload is too large. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php.

Comment: with var_dump : bool(true), and my server is correctly configured, i can upload files if the file name does not contain accents.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that there is some conflict of file_get_contents function and open_basedir directive of your php.ini file:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Try to use move_uploaded_file function before you read the file.
It will move uploaded file from temporary directory of your server  to specified directory, (open_basedir directive only effects the destination parameter of move_uploaded_file)

Comment: I even tried to use it like that, to avoid accents :

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pieceJointe']['tmp_name'], "/tmp/".$filenameWithoutAccents);
But it was the same problem.

And then I used file_get_contents($_FILES['pieceJointe']["/tmp/".$namewithoutaccents]);

Answer (score 0):

Isn't $_FILES['pieceJointe']['tmp_name'] just a file name name, instead of a valid full path?
Maybe move the file first with move_uploaded_file before opening it.

Comment: $_FILES['pieceJointe']['tmp_name'] contain a full path like "/tmp/phpzQdskC" for example.

Comment: but i see $_FILES['pieceJointe']['name'] contains something like fichiÃ©tÃ¨st.txt (instead of fichétèst here), can't it be an encoding problem, that is annoying file upload ?